# My MySQL results at Excel sheets doesn't work good

Tags: mysql, excel, ms-office, excel-2013

I have a Sheet with My SQL import data from hours numbers format (without date), but exceed 24:00:00
When I refresh and import data, Excel shows me this:
11:46:02
If I change the Hours Format to [h]:mm:ss Excel shows me this:
1001243:46:02
In the equation receipt, Excel shows me this:
20/03/2014  11:46:02

In this way, I think it imports data with today's date. Indeed I realize Excel should import the data with date of 01/01/1990 and then the sum kept correct. I think it's interpreting the exceeded hours after 23:59:59 as a date, but I just suppose.

I have another Sheet with the same database from MySQL and this numbers works correct, so I think the problem is at Excel 2013, but I can't find a solution in this.

The query is:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(ch.datafinal)),TIME(FROM‌​_UNIXTIME(ch.datainicial)))))) AS tempo, usu.nomecompleto FROM usuarios usu LEFT JOIN chat_historicocliente ch ON (usu.codusuario = ch.operador) WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(ch.datainicial)) = 02 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(ch.datainicial)) = 2014 GROUP BY usu.nomecompleto
```

All query with time in hour bigger than 24 hours have this trouble
Thanks

Comment: Check the column format. You can force it to text to keep the original value

Comment: Nothing happened, If I choose the format [h]:mm:ss, the result is the same.

Comment: How do you open the data in excel? Copy/Paste, Text file, ... Is there a chance the value gets corrupted before reaching the spreadsheet?

Comment: I import data from MySQL Querys Connection with ODBC Driver. The data updates automatically in tabels.

Comment: If I run a query at SQLYog (for example) it returns the result I want. But the Data at Excel it's in Unix format at the cells. I can't config Excel to keep format.

Comment: can you post your table structure and query?

Comment: Here http://imgur.com/kSIfAY3. The query is:
SELECT
 SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(ch.datafinal)),TIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(ch.datainicial)))))) AS tempo,
 usu.nomecompleto
FROM
 usuarios usu
 LEFT JOIN chat_historicocliente ch ON (usu.codusuario = ch.operador)
WHERE
 EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(ch.datainicial)) = 02
 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(ch.datainicial)) = 2014
GROUP BY usu.nomecompleto

All query with time in hour bigger than 24 hours have this trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "tempo" is the result of SEC_TO_TIME() which can be literal OR numerical based on your input.
The [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) says

```
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(2378);
        -> '00:39:38'
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(2378) + 0;
        -> 3938
```

Your are most likely falling under the second category

Comment: It returns other results, but still wrong. Excel imports it as date and changing cell format  doesn't change anything. I gave up trying to solve this because i spent a lot of time in this, I use SQLYog to execute the query and manually add to my tables. Thank you for helping me.